# What ports should I keep open to allow for ACME-based certificate renewal?

Tags: iptables, lets-encrypt

I'm hosting a website on a public-facing server. On this website, I'd like to have as-strict-as-possible firewall rules; part of this approach involves whitelisting by port.

I've opened SSH to a few trusted addresses, and I've configured `iptables` to allow traffic from anywhere on HTTP and HTTPS, but with an overall `DROP` policy on `INPUT`.

Now I'm trying to set up Let's Encrypt for a domain which is pointed at that box, but this always hangs until I run `iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT` for the duration of the certificate signing.

This is puzzling, since as far as I can tell:

- Proofs are generated in some specified subdirectory of `/var/www/`
- `acme-tiny` sends a signing request to `letsencrypt.org` over HTTPS
- The proofs are fetched over HTTP from that directory by LE's servers

... So the only ports that should need to be open are 80 and 443.

As described above, the script hangs on the very first domain which it tries to get validated (until a timeout occurs) unless I set my global `INPUT` policy to `ACCEPT`, which, ideally, I'd like to avoid.

This persists after whitelisting *all* traffic from `letsencrypt.org`, `acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org`, and `acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org`

What other ports and domains, and on what chains, should I whitelist to allow for `acme-tiny` to have regular access to the LE servers when a renewal needed?

Comment: AFAIK, unless configured otherwise, the challenge files need only be served over HTTP, not even HTTPS so opening port 80 should be plenty enough. Can you reach your web site when you try to  object to your web server? Also note, a stateful policy is often combined with a rule to allow related and established connections.

Comment: @Ginnungagap yup, I can connect over 80 (and even 443) with the stateful `DROP` policy. Can you tell me more about rules for related and established connections? I'm already whitelisting all `INPUT` on 80 and 443 with specific `OUTPUT` on the same ports.

Comment: With a similar configuration but with a first RULE of `iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`, any incoming connection that relates to a previously established connection (so one that passed the firewall) is automatically accepted. Running something along these lines, my renewal works, it shouldn't be an issue that it isn't there but can you at least test it, I'll look into it further once I'm in front of a computer